# Does spring inject any beans provided in the @Configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If I have a `@Configuration` class where I have a bean like below, will the `dataMap` be resolved in the constructor of the `DataService` class. What type of dependency injection is this? Is it `by type` because the name for sure doesn't match?

```
@Bean
public Map<String, List<Data>> data() {
    final Map<String, List<Data>> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    readings.put("1", new Data());
    return dataMap;
}
```

and a class

```
@Service
public class DataService {

    private final Map<String, List<Data>> information;

    public DataService(Map<String, List<Data>> information) {
        this.information = information;
    }
}
```

Comment: Injection, with java config, is by default by type, if no type is found it will fallback to name (either explicitly or by using the field name).

Answer (score 1):

`@Configuration` annotation serves as a placeholder to mention that whichever classes annotated with `@Configuration` are holding the bean definitions!

When Spring application comes up, spring framework will read these definitions and create `beans (or simply objects)` in `IOC (Inversion of control) container` These would be Spring managed objects/beans !

To answer your question, it should create a bean and this is a `setter` based injection!

However, your `@Bean` must be some user defined or business entity class in ideal scenarios!

**Few links for you to refer to:**

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2096/playing-around-with-spring-bean-configuration
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/different-types-dependency-injection-spring-kashif-masood/

Comment: `setter based injection!`? I don't see any setters. I see constructor injection